# SQL - count amount of occurences for items in different price diapasons

Tags: sql

I have a question about SQL, and I honestly tried to search methods before asking. I will give an abstract (but precise) description below, and will greatly appreciate your example of solution (SQL query).

**What I have:**

1. Table A with **category ids** of the items and **prices** (in USD) for each item. **category id** has *int* type of value, **price** is *string* and looks like "USD 200000000" (real value is multiplied by 10^7). Tables also has a **kind** column with *int* type of value.
2. Table B with relation of *category id* and *name*.

**What I need:**

Get a table with price diapasons (like 0-100 | 100-200 | ...) as column names and count amount of items for each *category id* (as lines names) in all of the price diapasons. All results must be filtered by **kind** parameter (from table A) with value *3*.

**Questions, that I encountered (and which caused to ask for an example of SQL query):**

1. Cut *"USD* from **price** string value, divide it by 10^7 and convert to float.
2. Gather diapasons of **price** values (0-100 | 100-200 | ...), with given step in the given interval (max price is considered as unknown at the start). Example: step *100* on 0-500 interval, and step *200* for values >500.
3. Put diapasons of **price** values into column names of the result table.
4. For each diapason, count amount of items in each category (category_id). Left limit of diapason shall not be considered (e.g. on 1000-1200 diapason, items with price 1000 shall not be considered).
5. Using B table, display *name* instead of *category id*.

Response is appreciated, ignorance will be understood.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: lets imagine, that it is PostgreSQL
(no offense, I just can`t tell it, but the syntax of query is expected to be the same as described from the beginning of this article - https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/default.asp )

Answer (score 1):

If you only need category ids, then you do not need `B`.  What you are looking for is conditional aggregation, something like:

```
select category_id,
       sum(case when cast(substring(price, 4, 100) as int)/10000000 < 100 then 1 else 0 end) as price_000_100
       sum(case when cast(substring(price, 4, 100) as int)/10000000 >= 100 and cast(substring(price, 4, 100) as int)/10000000 < 200
                then 1 else 0
           end) as price_100_200,
       . . .                 
from a
group by category_id
```

Comment: Gordon, many thanks for your suggestion!

But in this case, I will need to write an undefined amount of "sum" lines. Can I automate generation of diapasons based on the above-mentioned condition? Let me know, if my description lacks something.

Comment: @AntonFromButovo: you can't have an "undefined" amount of columns in a SQL query. The number of columns must be defined _before_ the query is executed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Potentially possible with SQL Server using STUFF, PIVOT and dynamic SQL - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: @Alan: with dynamic SQL you still don't get rid of that limitation. The only difference is that you first calculate the number of columns, then _generate_ a statement where that number is known when you execute it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do what you describe.

That is because to do (3) you need a pivot aka crosstab, and this is not in ANSI SQL. Each DBMS has it's own implementation. Plus dynamic columns in a pivot table are an additional complication.

For example, Postgres calls it a "crosstab" and requires the tablefunc module to be installed. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905) and the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html). Compare to SQL Server, which uses the [PIVOT command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

You can get close using reasonably standard SQL.

Here is an example based on SQLite. A little bit of conversion would provide a solution for other systems, e.g. `SUBSTR` would be `substring(string [from int] [for int])` in postgre.

Assuming a data table of format:

[image: data table]

and a category name table of:

[image: category name table]

then the following code will produce:

[image: output as list]

```
WITH dataCTE AS
    (SELECT product_id AS 'ID', CAST(SUBSTR(price, 5) AS INT)/1000000 AS 'USD',
    CASE WHEN (CAST(SUBSTR(price, 5) AS INT)/1000000) <= 500 THEN
        100 ELSE 200
        END AS 'Interval'
    FROM data
    WHERE kind = 3),
groupCTE AS
    (SELECT dataCTE.ID AS 'ID', dataCTE.USD AS 'USD', dataCTE.Interval AS 'Interval',
    CASE WHEN dataCTE.Interval = 100 THEN 
        CAST(dataCTE.USD AS INT)/100
    ELSE
        (CAST(dataCTE.USD-500 AS INT)/200)+5
    END AS 'GroupID'
    FROM dataCTE),
cleanCTE AS
    (SELECT *, CASE WHEN groupCTE.Interval = 100 THEN
        CAST(groupCTE.GroupID *100 AS VARCHAR) 
        || '-' || 
        CAST((groupCTE.GroupID *100)+99 AS VARCHAR)
    ELSE
        CAST(((groupCTE.GroupID-5)*200)+500 AS VARCHAR) 
        || '-' || 
        CAST(((groupCTE.GroupID-5)*200)+500+199 AS VARCHAR) 
    END AS 'diapason'
    FROM groupCTE
    INNER JOIN cat_name AS cn ON groupCTE.ID = cn.cat_id)
SELECT *
FROM cleanCTE;
```

If you modify the last `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT name, diapason, COUNT(diapason)
FROM cleanCTE
GROUP BY name, diapason;
```

then you get a grouped output:

[image: output as group]

This is as close as you will get without specifying the exact system; even then you will have a problem with dynamically creating the column names.

Comment: Alan, thank you so much for your explanation & example! It helped me to craft the proper solution for my issue.